# C++ Heterogenous Dictionary

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++ and I recently found out that we can initialize a collection of strings by using the following code:

```cpp
map <string,string> myArray;
myArray["key1"] = "value1";
myArray["key2"] = "value2";

cout<<myArray["key1"]<<endl; //result: value1
```

But what if I have to assign to `key2` not a string but another collection? Here is how I suppose it would look:

```cpp
map <string, ???another map???> myArray;

map<string,string> secondArray;
secondArray["foo"] = "bar";

myArray["key1"] = "value1";
myArray["key2"] = secondArray;

cout<<myArray["key2"]["foo"]<<endl; //expected result: bar
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @Cat Maps are associative arrays are they not?

Comment: @anirudh4444 They are associative arrays, but the term *array* by itself is usually associated with constant time element access.

Comment: @anirudh4444: Well, associative arrays are not arrays, then (and I don't like that name, anyway). Arrays have a contiguous storage. Mappings usually don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the questioner seems to have accepted one of the answers, this is just a
supplement.
If `Boost` is allowed, [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html) might meet the purpose.
For example, the following code prints `bar` as in the question.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  using namespace boost;
  typedef map<string,string> map_t;
  map <string, variant<string, map_t> > myArray;

  map_t secondArray;
  secondArray["foo"] = "bar";

  myArray["key1"] = "value1";
  myArray["key2"] = secondArray;

  cout<<get< map_t >( myArray["key2"] )["foo"]<<endl;
}
```

Here is a test on [ideone](http://ideone.com/sepRH).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> myArray;
```

which will let the values corresponding to different keys take on different types.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `myArray` as

```
map <string, map <string,string> > myArray;
```

Obviously you cannot do `myArray["key1"] = "value1";` anymore, but that's the trade-off of a strongly typed language.